# Iterating over array of structs without size in declaration

Tags: c, arrays, struct, size, declaration

I've been having problems with trying to iterate over array of structs. The setup is as following:

data.h

```
typedef struct data {
    char *name;
    char *age;
} data;
data array_of_data[];
```

data.c

```
data array_of_data[4] = {
    {"John", "24"},
    {"Melissa", "32"},
    {"Ludwing", "98"}
};
```

main.c

```
#include "data.h"
int main() {
    int i=0;
    while(&array_of_data[i] != NULL) {
        do_something();
        i++;
    }
    return 0;    
}
```

I can't have number of elements in declaration in .h file. So iterating with for loop and sizeof, or while loop doesn't work. With my solution I'm getting an 'undefined reference' error. I don't understand why. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no variable called `data_array` declared / defined. Show us the actual code.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it. Actual code is too large for a stackoverflow post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest ways to process an array without giving its length is to use a guard value, for example `NULL` as last value.

This would result in code like this:

```c
data array_of_data[4] = {
    {"John", "24"},
    {"Melissa", "32"},
    {"Ludwing", "98"},
    {NULL, NULL},
};

int main() {
    int i=0;
    while(array_of_data[i].name != NULL) {
        printf("[%d] %s, %s\n", i, array_of_data[i].name, array_of_data[i].age);
        i++;    
    }
}
```